# Align all the widgets of row to top

Tags: flutter

I have a `Row` which contains three widget, `[icon, button, text]`. I want all of them to align at the top. If the text is long everything is fine. But if the text is short, It is not align.

Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/e4iRVSFz

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  TextButton(
    style: ButtonStyle(
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft
    ),

    onPressed: () {
      // Add your middle widget click logic here
    },
    child: Text(
      'Short',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
        decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

try add a `ButtonStyle` to `TextButton`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is occur because you use Textbutton here. By default Textbutton has some height and width thats you didn't see the proper alignment.  So replace TextButton with GestureDetector and see the magic.

```
Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    constraints:
                        BoxConstraints(minHeight: 24.0), // Set a minimum height
                    child: TextButton( // use GestureDetector and see the magic
                      onPressed: () {
                        // Add your middle widget click logic here
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Short',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually it was helpful. And `GestureDetector` gave me idea about `InkWell` as well.

Comment: If you want splash area then use InkWell otherwise use GestureDetector

Answer (score 0):

TextButtons have an iternal padding. It helps to remove this by giving a style that removes them like this

```
    child: TextButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        minimumSize: Size.zero, // Set this
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // and this
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        // Add your middle widget click logic here
      },
      child: Text(
        'Short',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.blue,
          decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: Still, The button remains unmoved.